# JBeret and JSR352, some clarifications on restart and persistentdata

Tags: java, jsr352, jberet, jbatch

I'm currently using **JBeret** as the batch implementation of **JSR 352** spec.

#### FIRST ISSUE

I'm tring to reproduct a chunk job where processor fails and store restart position so I can restart from last succesfull index.

This is the **Reader** class

```
@Named
public class MyReaderFails extends AbstractItemReader {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    List<Integer> output;
    int index;

    @Inject
    StepContext stepContext;

    @Override
    public Object readItem() throws Exception {
        logger.info("reading item: {}", index);
        return output.get(index++);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Serializable checkpoint) throws Exception {
        logger.info("open: {}", checkpoint);
        int startIndex = Optional.ofNullable(checkpoint).map(Integer.class::cast).orElse(0);
        output = IntStream.range(startIndex, 30).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable checkpointInfo() throws Exception {
        logger.info("current checkpoint: {}", index);
        return index;
    }
}
```

This is the **Processor**

```
@Named
public class MyProcessorFails implements ItemProcessor {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    @BatchProperty(name = "itemnumerror")
    Integer itemnumerror;

    @Inject
    @BatchProperty(name = "error")
    Boolean error;

    @Override
    public Object processItem(Object o) throws Exception {
        logger.info("input: {}", o);
        if (itemnumerror == o && error) {
            throw new RuntimeException(); //first time batch is started, throws an error
        }
        Integer output = (Integer)o + 30;

        return output;
    }
}
```

the **Writer**

```
@Named
public class MyWriterFails extends AbstractItemWriter {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    StepContext stepContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("squid:S2629")
    @Override
    public void writeItems(List<Object> list) throws Exception {
        logger.info("output: {}", list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" , ", "{", "}")));
        ArrayList<Integer> processed = Optional.ofNullable(stepContext.getPersistentUserData()).map(ArrayList.class::cast).orElse(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        processed.addAll(list.stream().map(Integer.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        stepContext.setPersistentUserData(processed);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable checkpointInfo() throws Exception {
        return Optional.of(stepContext.getPersistentUserData()).map(List.class::cast).map(List::size).orElse(0);
    }
}
```

Now I'd expect that if job fails, it set the **JOB_EXECUTION**.**RESTART_POSITION** column to the index returned from *checkpointInfo*, but this doesn't happen.

Therefore, when I try to restart the job from the last id, checkpoint is always null.

How can I store checkpoint in order to retrieve it from the *open* method ?

#### SECOND ISSUE

On the app test I often see setting persistence user data from stepContext object (See also my writer implementation).
What is the really usage of this ? What can I really do with saved data?

I also guess that, when working with thousand of records, this practice can lead to critical memory overhead.

Any hints ?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the *RESTART_POSITION* column name, since here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273235?_sscc=t  it seems to be more about specifying a step to restart at, within the job... and not a reader/writer checkpoint within a step.       As far as the separate question about persistent user data, it seems like it might be better to break that off into a separate question;  it doesn't seem too closely related to the issue you're having with checkpointing.

Comment: As @ScottKurz pointed out, `RESTART_POSITION` is jberet-specific, and you don't need it to restart a job execution. It will alway restart from the beginning of the failed chunk, most likely not the exact data item that caused prevoius failure.  If the previous execution failed during the first chunk, then the restart job execution will start from the first data item.

Comment: @cheng no, I make fails the processor on the second chunk by throwing a runtime exception. I'd expect to restart at second chunk, but checkpoint is always null. How can I get checkpoint working?

Comment: I tested with your reader, processor and writer classes, and got the correct restart behavior, i.e., the restart execution starts from the failed chunk in the previous execution. I modified your reader class to return null at the end of the input stream instead of throwing IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: @cheng shame on me, it was just a typo on my test. 
After restart I did jobOperator.getJobExecution(oldid) instead of newid. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

This is the job xml I used in my testing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job id="fail-restart" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/jobXML_1_0.xsd"
     version="1.0">
    <step id="fail-restart.step1">
        <chunk item-count="10">
            <reader ref="myReaderFails">
                <properties>
                    <property name="logger" value="java.util.logging.Logger"/>
                </properties>
            </reader>
            <processor ref="myProcessorFails">
            <properties>
                <property name="logger" value="java.util.logging.Logger"/>
                <property name="error" value="#{jobParameters['error']}"/>
                <property name="itemnumerror" value="15"/>
            </properties>
            </processor>
            <writer ref="myWriterFails">
            <properties>
                <property name="logger" value="java.util.logging.Logger"/>
            </properties>
            </writer>
        </chunk>
    </step>
</job>
```

This is the test method:

```java
public class SimpleIT {
    private static final JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();

    @Test
    public void failRestart() throws Exception {
        final Properties params = new Properties();
        params.setProperty("error", String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE));

        final long jobExecutionId = jobOperator.start("fail-restart", params);
        JobExecutionImpl jobExecution = (JobExecutionImpl) jobOperator.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId);
        jobExecution.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.FAILED, jobExecution.getBatchStatus());

        params.setProperty("error", String.valueOf(Boolean.FALSE));
        final long restartId = jobOperator.restart(jobExecutionId, params);
        jobExecution = (JobExecutionImpl) jobOperator.getJobExecution(restartId);
        jobExecution.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getBatchStatus());
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails open
INFO: open: null
output list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 0
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 0
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 1
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 1
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 2
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 2
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 3
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 3
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 4
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 4
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 5
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 5
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 6
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 6
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 7
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 7
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 8
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 8
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 9
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 9
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyWriterFails writeItems
INFO: output: {30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 38 , 39}
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails checkpointInfo
INFO: current checkpoint: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 11
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 11
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 12
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 12
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 13
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 13
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 14
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 14
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 15
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 15
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner readProcessWriteItems
ERROR: ProcessingInfo{count=6, timerExpired=false, itemState=RUNNING, chunkState=RUNNING, checkpointPosition=9, readPosition=15, failurePoint=null}
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner run
ERROR: item-count=10, time-limit=0, skip-limit=-1, skipCount=0, retry-limit=-1, retryCount=0
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner run
ERROR: JBERET000007: Failed to run job fail-restart, fail-restart.step1, org.jberet.job.model.Chunk@7f938562
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at sample.MyProcessorFails.processItem(MyProcessorFails.java:38)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner.processItem(ChunkRunner.java:422)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner.readProcessWriteItems(ChunkRunner.java:335)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.ChunkRunner.run(ChunkRunner.java:208)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.runBatchletOrChunk(StepExecutionRunner.java:225)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.run(StepExecutionRunner.java:144)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runStep(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:164)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runFromHeadOrRestartPoint(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:88)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.JobExecutionRunner.run(JobExecutionRunner.java:60)
    at org.jberet.spi.JobExecutor$1.run(JobExecutor.java:99)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails open
INFO: open: 10
output list: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 0
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 1
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 11
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 2
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 12
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 3
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 13
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 4
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 14
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 5
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 15
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 6
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 16
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 7
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 17
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 8
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 18
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 9
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 19
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyWriterFails writeItems
INFO: output: {40 , 41 , 42 , 43 , 44 , 45 , 46 , 47 , 48 , 49}
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails checkpointInfo
INFO: current checkpoint: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 10
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 20
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 11
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 21
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 12
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 22
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 13
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 23
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 14
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 24
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 15
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 25
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 16
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 26
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 17
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 27
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 18
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 28
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 19
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyProcessorFails processItem
INFO: input: 29
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyWriterFails writeItems
INFO: output: {50 , 51 , 52 , 53 , 54 , 55 , 56 , 57 , 58 , 59}
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails checkpointInfo
INFO: current checkpoint: 20
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails readItem
INFO: reading item: 20
Dec 09, 2019 11:36:18 AM sample.MyReaderFails checkpointInfo
INFO: current checkpoint: 21
Weld SE container STATIC_INSTANCE shut down by shutdown hook

Process finished with exit code 0
```